# Regex that allows mobile numbers starting with * or #

Tags: regex

I need a regex that matches a mobile phone number(with a **maximum of 9 digits**) starting with  *  or  # , like these ones:

```
#964418878
*8745858
*985686869
```

Hope you can help me out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just nine  consecutive digits?

```
^(\*|#)\d{1,9}$
```

Replace `1` with the minimum number of digits you want to have.

---

This is a good place to start learning regular expressions: http://www.regular-expressions.info/

Comment: Fairly sure most regex engines will vomit something about a lack of a term before what it thinks is a `*` quantifier.

Comment: yep just 9 digits starting with either # or *

Comment: @Platinum Azure: I escaped the quantifier while you commented :)

Comment: that was quick .Thank you so much to you all!! :D

Answer (score 3):

The following should do what you want:

```
/^[*#]\d{1,9}$/
```

This assume your strings ONLY consist of the phone numbers, one per string. If you're just checking that they exist in a larger string, remove the `^` and `$` characters.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this, depending on the regex flavor:

```
/[#*]?\d{1,9}/
```

`\d` is an alias for `[0-9]`, so if the former isn't supported on your platform (is there such a beast?) then use the latter. Also, this is the syntax for a find, if you want a match, add `^` and `$` to beginning and end, respectively.

Comment: No need to escape characters inside a character class (at least not those listed in your regex ;))

Comment: No, the only special character inside a character class is `-`, and only if it does *not* occur at the beginning or end of the class (and obviously `]` needed to be escaped too).

Comment: Yeah, I'm pretty sure only `]`, `^` (if you list that first), and maybe `[` need to be escaped. (EDIT: Forgot the hyphen, haha. Just ignore this comment please)

Comment: @Platinum Azure: Ah and I forgot `^` :D But now the characters should be complete ;)